# Python Converting Velocity vs Distance graph into Acceleration graph

Tags: python

I have a section of my code for a lap time simulator of which looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T8_Angle = 180
T8_Radius = 80.5352283/2
T8_Length = T8_Radius * (T8_Angle*(np.pi/180))

T8_Velo = np.sqrt(uy*g*T8_Radius)

St1Length = 400

dsa1 = 1
vela1 = [T8_Velo]
sa1 = [0.]

while sa1[-1] < St1Length:
    Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * vela1[-1]**2
    Ap = ((PMax / ((m * vela1[-1]) + 1e-9)) - (Fd / m)) / g  
    yw = 0
    Aw = (((b * np.sqrt((yw)**2 + g**2)) / h) - ((Fd * ha) / (m * h))) / g
    Wheelie_Min = np.minimum(Ap, Aw)
    vela1_new = np.sqrt(vela1[-1]**2 + 2*Wheelie_Min*dsa1*g)
    vela1.append(vela1_new)

    sa1_new = sa1[-1] + dsa1 
    sa1.append(sa1_new)


T1_Angle = 90
T1_Length = 315
T1_Radius = T1_Length/(2*np.pi*(T1_Angle/360))

T1_Velo = np.sqrt(uy*g*T1_Radius)

dsd1 = 1
veld1 = [T1_Velo]
sd1 = [St1Length]

while sd1[-1] > 0:
    Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * veld1[-1]**2
    yw = 0
    Ad = (((g * ux * (np.sqrt(1 - (((yw)/ g)**2) * (1 / uy**2))) + (Fd / m))) * -1) / g  
    As = ((((w-b) * np.sqrt((yw)**2 + g**2)) / h) + ((Fd * ha) / (m *h))) / (g *-1)
    Deceleration_Max = np.maximum(Ad, As)
    veld1_new = np.sqrt(veld1[-1]**2 - 2*Deceleration_Max*g*dsd1)
    veld1.append(veld1_new)

    sd1_new = sd1[-1] - dsd1 
    sd1.append(sd1_new)

min_vel1 = []
for i in range(len(sa1)):
    s1 = sa1[i]
    v1_1 = vela1[i]
    v2_1 = veld1[-i-1]
    min_v1 = min(v1_1, v2_1)
    min_vel1.append(min_v1)

St1Last = sa1[-1]
St1T1 = St1Last+T1_Length
fig, lv = plt.subplots()
lv.plot(sa1, min_vel1, 'b')
lv.hlines(T1_Velo, St1Last, St1T1, 'b')

St2Length = 900
St2_Total = St2Length + St1T1

dsa2 = 1
vela2 = [T1_Velo]
sa2 = [St1T1]

while sa2[-1] < St2_Total:
    Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * vela2[-1]**2
    Ap = ((PMax / ((m * vela2[-1]) + 1e-9)) - (Fd / m)) / g  
    yw = 0
    Aw = (((b * np.sqrt((yw)**2 + g**2)) / h) - ((Fd * ha) / (m * h))) / g
    Wheelie_Min = np.minimum(Ap, Aw)
    vela2_new = np.sqrt(vela2[-1]**2 + 2*Wheelie_Min*dsa2*g)
    vela2.append(vela2_new)

    sa2_new = sa2[-1] + dsa2 
    sa2.append(sa2_new)

T2_Angle = 180
T2_Radius = 180
T2_Length = T2_Radius * (T2_Angle*(np.pi/180))

T2_Velo = np.sqrt(uy*g*T2_Radius)

dsd2 = 1
veld2 = [T2_Velo]
sd2 = [St2Length]

while sd2[-1] > 0:
    Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * veld2[-1]**2
    yw = 0
    Ad = (((g * ux * (np.sqrt(1 - (((yw)/ g)**2) * (1 / uy**2))) + (Fd / m))) * -1) / g  
    As = ((((w-b) * np.sqrt((yw)**2 + g**2)) / h) + ((Fd * ha) / (m *h))) / (g *-1)
    Deceleration_Max = np.maximum(Ad, As)
    veld2_new = np.sqrt(veld2[-1]**2 - 2*Deceleration_Max*g*dsd2)
    veld2.append(veld2_new)

    sd2_new = sd2[-1] - dsd2 
    sd2.append(sd2_new)

min_vel2 = []
for i in range(len(sa2)):
    s2 = sa2[i]
    v1_2 = vela2[i]
    v2_2 = veld2[-i-1]
    min_v2 = min(v1_2, v2_2)
    min_vel2.append(min_v2)

St2Last = sa2[-1]
St2T2 = St2Last+T2_Length
lv.plot(sa2, min_vel2, 'b')
lv.hlines(T2_Velo, St2Last, St2T2, 'b')
plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
plt.ylabel('Velocity (m/s)')
```

[image]

My question is how would I convert this velocity into its acceleration. I have tried to making Wheelie_Min and Deceleration_Max arrays and plotting that whilst comparing them as seen from above with the for loop however the graphs are always positive or always negative of which isn't right as the velocity drops, the acceleration should be negative. I suppose I could perform calculus on the graph and differentiate it however, I don't know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: assuming you have 2 speeds, at 2 timestamps, the acceleration is given by `(speed[t2] - speed[t1]) / (t2 - t1)`

Comment: I have not kept track of time at all in my code as I did not need to

Comment: you can infer the time from `diff(distance) / speed` for small enough intervals